# Creating a responsive div with complex objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am creating an admin panel with charts/images, etc.

I am failing to make it responsive.

All images are svg's, I used charts.js framework to create the pie chart.

This is an example of a div I have

[image: chart]

This is the html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alerts-chart-wrapper">
            <canvas id="alertsChart" style="float: left;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row alert-row">
            <div class="entitys-icons icon-1"> </div>
            <div class="alert-entity-name"> Users </div>
            <div class="entity-alerts-count">28</div>
        </div>
        ...(3 more rows)
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.alert-row {
    padding: 0% 15% 3% 5%;
}

.entitys-icons {
    background: url('/Areas/WebApp/app/main_page_assets/02_general_alerts_icons.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    background-size: 77px;
    float: left;
}

.entitys-icons.icon-1 {
    background-position: 0 2px;
}

.alert-entity-name {
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.entity-alerts-count {
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.alerts-chart-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now the problem is the circle grows and shrinks depending on the resolution, but the rows arent.

Here is a screenshot of the problem when the width shrinks(the circle and th rows must be aligned):

[image]

What is the strategy to use here? I thought maybe i will use media's with fixed size, but the best solution for me is that the rows height will change accordingly.

Comment: Could you create JSFiddle with your code?

Comment: Set the rows to 25% height of parent? Or am I missing the point of the question?

Comment: @DBS please look at my edit(added a print-screen when i shrink the screen width), the circles height gets smaller and the rows doesnt

Comment: I can see the problem, but without seeing the CSS (or preferably a reproducing example, e.g. Stack Snippet or JSFiddle ) It's tough to know what will help.

Comment: @DBS added the css, see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Inside the head tag, configure the right viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the other grid options to specify the sizes as the screen changes resolution.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

For mobile you'll want to use the `.col-sm-` prefix.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="alerts-chart-wrapper">
            <canvas id="alertsChart" style="float: left;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 alert-row">
               <div class="entitys-icons icon-1"> </div>
               <div class="alert-entity-name"> Users </div>
               <div class="entity-alerts-count">28</div>
            </div>
            ...(3 more **col**)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not true, I also used media queries, thats not helping because the content and the height of the rows is not changing

Comment: I made some changes to help reflect what could be wrong. The class 'row' isn't responsive, columns are. You need to specify columns and their prefix inside the row.